# Sortable like vue.js component (without npm / webpack) or use jQuery plugin within vue area

Tags: html, jquery, vue.js

I have a ASP.NET Core application which renders tables on the serverside, some are quite complex.
I used to use sorttable: Make all your tables sortable for make the tables sortable; now as I have included vue.js (2.0, without npm / webpack), the jquery plugin obviously does no longer work properly.

Now, before i transition fully over to 100% clientside table rendering - which I want to avoid for now, if its possible, cause its complex - is there something similar to add sorting to a rendered html with vue or is that concept that old and no longer viable in vue.js and other modern frameworks?

So, questions are:

How to make sorttable work in vue.js are (without npm / webpack)
Or how to add something like that to a already server rendered html with vue?
Looking forward and regards, Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it. That was a journey :-)

Sorttable script: https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

The script:

```
Vue.component('date-table', {
    template: '<div><slot></slot></div>',
    props: ['innerHtml'],
    mounted: function () {
        var self = this;

        sorttable.makeSortable(this.$el.firstChild);
    },
    beforeDestroy: function () {

    }
});
```

The markup:

```
<date-table v-once>
    HERE IS MY ORDINARY HTML WHICH SHOULD BE SORTED BY 
    "sortable.makeSortable(...."
</data-table>
```